# 403 - Insufficient Permission to write data to Google spread sheet using Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write data to Google spreadsheet using Java programming language. I can read data from the sheet but can't write data to the sheet. I'm always getting 
`"message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"`
error. I've tried to change the scopes to `SPREADSHEETS, DRIVE` but did not solve the issue.

Here is code:

```
package io.com.google_sheet;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.AppendValuesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.UpdateValuesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SheetsQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheet with Java";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
//    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS, SheetsScopes.DRIVE);
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = SheetsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

         // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
//        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
//                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
//                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
//                .setAccessType("offline")
//                .build();
//        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
//        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");


      GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
              GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
      return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");


    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final String spreadsheetId = "11ghLf1MnN4yedz5WYMCdV9tmaOu9G8B-R8DLm5fs-Io";//"1QF0uX9WFgA3L3zxOtFQbyHYWfvi88nzZiLrV6-LbavQ"; //"1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
         Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build(); 

        ValueRange value = new ValueRange()
                .setValues(Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList((Object)"Nikol", "Peter", "12:20")
                        ));

        try {
            AppendValuesResponse appendData = service.spreadsheets().values()
                    .append(spreadsheetId, "Google Sheet with Java", value)
                    .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERTED").setInsertDataOption("INSERT_ROWS")
                    .setIncludeValuesInResponse(true)
                    .execute();

            System.out.println("Successfully entered data");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not add the data with error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 Could not add the data with error: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I've looked similar question here in Stackoverflow and some in Github but could find the solution.

Could you please check where I have wrong so that I'm getting the error?

Comment: This is a common error if you don't refresh the token (StoredCredential file under tokens directory) after updating the scopes. Could you try deleting the StoredCredential file, run the application, and grant the permissions again which will generate a new token with the updated scopes?

Comment: @AndresDuarte, thanks, it works.
I've another question, I'm writing this code to write data to Google spread sheets from RESTful API. So at the end I will make a jar file, put the jar file in server. During enabling the Google sheet API, I have few option to chose to Configure  OAuth client, as now I'm working in my local machine, I have chosen the "Desktop App" option. To make sure that this code will work with my RESTful API should I chose other options like "web server"?

Comment: For a new question unrelated to the problem you need to open a new StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common error if you don't update the refresh token (StoredCredential file under tokens directory) after updating the scopes.

You need to delete the StoredCredential file, run the application, and grant the permissions again which will generate a new StoredCredential file with the updated scopes.